# Why my Spring project doesn't work after adding filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have completely working project and I want to add security to it. After adding DelegatingFilterProxy to web.xml it doesn't work. Here it is:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
    /WEB-INF/spring/securityContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ContextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <display-name>SpringSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
    <filter-name>SpringSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

All of my spring-security related dependencies are of version 4.1.0.RELEASE . I can see in my logs that the filter was loaded but there is no error provided so I struggle to figure out why webpage doesn't load. Here is my securityContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

 <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="testuser" authorities="ROLE_SUPERADMIN" password="password"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>


<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/test" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:form-login />
</security:http>
```

These are my logs:

```
2016-06-28 18:59:40 INFO  ContextLoader:305 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:578 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 28 18:59:41 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/securityContext.xml]
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  SpringSecurityCoreVersion:74 - You are running with Spring Security Core 4.1.0.RELEASE
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  SecurityNamespaceHandler:78 - Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.1.0.RELEASE
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser:173 - Creating access control expression attribute 'denyAll' for /**
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser:173 - Creating access control expression attribute 'permitAll' for /test
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  AuthenticationConfigBuilder:539 - No login page configured. The default internal one will be used. Use the 'login-page' attribute to set the URL of the login page.
2016-06-28 18:59:41 INFO  HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser:306 - Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
2016-06-28 18:59:42 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-06-28 18:59:42 INFO  Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-06-28 18:59:42 INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-06-28 18:59:42 INFO  Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-06-28 18:59:43 INFO  Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-06-28 18:59:43 INFO  LobCreatorBuilder:97 - HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
2016-06-28 18:59:43 INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator:62 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2016-06-28 18:59:43 INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-06-28 18:59:43 INFO  Version:30 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
2016-06-28 18:59:44 INFO  DefaultSecurityFilterChain:43 - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/'], []
2016-06-28 18:59:44 INFO  DefaultSecurityFilterChain:43 - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4e8f2204, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@184da4ba, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4c0addcf, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@60cd8a95, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@57e50b8a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@22781db8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@3886489d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3493e43a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4b550079, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@29a24176, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@23ea267f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@8f3b40c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6b462ba3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@50d46e4c]
2016-06-28 18:59:44 INFO  DefaultFilterChainValidator:154 - Checking whether login URL '/login' is accessible with your configuration
2016-06-28 18:59:44 INFO  ContextLoader:345 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4021 ms
2016-06-28 18:59:44 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:960 - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 28 18:59:41 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
cze 28, 2016 6:59:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6515 ms
```

Comment: Have you added the servlet part to your web.xml? http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

Comment: if i remember correctly, your filter needs to be named springSecurityFilterChain rather than SpringSecurityFilterChain (lowercase first letter) in order to match the name of the filter bean created by the security configuration

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score -1):

It worked after changing SpringSecurityFilterChain to springSecurityFilterChain. The first letter has to be lower case